# How to set recurring payment in paypal standard with different initial amount for the first month in php?

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-subscriptions

I found the code to create recurring payment profile using paypal standard but I want to charge user with different amount for the first month and then want to create recurring profile from the next month with different amount. Is this possible? I searched a lot but couldn't get the desired result. Please guide me.

This is the code I have right now :

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but20.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Ravinder

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use `a1, p1, t1` along with the variables that you are already using.  The following would charge 5.00 for the first month.

```
<input type="hidden" name="a1" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t1" value="M">
```

Comment: I want to charge 5 immediately at subscription creation and by 10 from next month and further. Do i need to setup `a1=5,p1=1,t1=M` and `a3=10,p3=1,t3=M`? Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

As PP_MTS_Chad said, you'll want to use the Trial Period values.

You can set up to two Trial Periods, at whatever amount and duration you want.

a1/p1/t1 for the first trial and then a2/p2/t2 for the second.

You can find the list of variables you can use here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Answer (score 0):

PayPal provides two trial period variables (a1/p1/t1 and a2/p2/t2) and one recurring variable (a3/p3/t3).

you may use first trial for days and second for Weeks/Months/Year as below,

```
<input type="hidden" name="a1" value="5.00">

<input type="hidden" name="p1" value="5">

<input type="hidden" name="t1" value="D">

<input type="hidden" name="a2" value="150.00">

<input type="hidden" name="p2" value="1">

<input type="hidden" name="t2" value="W/M/Y">
```

but period has some limits,

days - upto 90 days

Months - upto 24 months

weeks - upto 54 weeks

year - upto 5 years